# AccountTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: ()

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, developer-console, developer

I have called Apex class 2 from Apex class1. During creating a new Account in Salesforce getting an error.Please anyone help on this issue.

### Errore details

Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger AccountTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AccountTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: ()

### Apex Class 1:

public class INTLAccountTriggerService{

```
public static void afterInsert(List<Account> triggerNew, Map<Id, Account> triggerNewMap)
{

    ZIP_alignment_account test = new ZIP_alignment_account();
    test.assignTerritory(triggerNew);
 }
}
```

### Apex Class 2:

public class ZIP_alignment_account {

```
public void assignTerritory(List<Account> accList){
    
        for (Account a : accList){
        system.debug('Accountfromtrigger Id-->'+a.id);
        system.debug('Accountfromtrigger Name-->'+a.name);
    }
    List<ZTS_AccountTerritory__c> lstAT2Insert = new List<ZTS_AccountTerritory__c>();
    Set<String> zipcodes=new Set<String>(); 
    Set<String> marketSet = new Set<String>();
    Set<String> zipMarketKey =new Set<String>();
    List<Account> lstBricks = new List<Account>();
    
    for(Account acc:accList){
        if(!String.isBlank(acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c) && acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c != ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.MARKET_VAL && acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c != ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.UK_MARKET_VAL){
            zipcodes.add(acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c);
        }else if(acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c == ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.MARKET_VAL){
            zipcodes.add(acc.ZTS_EU_State_County_Value__c);
        }else if(!String.isBlank(acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c) && acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c == ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.UK_MARKET_VAL){
            zipcodes.add(acc.ZTS_EU_UK_PC4_from_Postalcode__c);
        }
        marketSet.add(acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c);
    }
    
    if(!zipcodes.isEmpty()){
        
        //Query ziptobrick 
        List<ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c> ziptoBrickList = [SELECT Name,ZTS_EU_ZipCode__c,ZTS_EU_BrickCode__c,ZTS_EU_Market__c,ZTS_EU_ZipPostalCode__c,ZTS_EU_Inactive__c,ZTS_EU_Query_Ext_ID__c,ZTS_EU_BrickCode__r.Name,ZTS_EU_BrickCode__r.ZTS_EU_Inactive__c,ZTS_EU_BrickCode__r.ZTS_EU_Territory__r.name 
                                                        FROM ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c 
                                                        WHERE ZTS_EU_Query_Ext_ID__c IN :zipcodes 
                                                        AND Name != '' 
                                                        AND ZTS_EU_BrickCode__r.ZTS_EU_Inactive__c = false 
                                                        AND ZTS_EU_Inactive__c = false 
                                                        AND ZTS_EU_Market__c IN : marketSet];
        //Code By Shefali
        for(ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c zpToBk :ziptoBrickList){ 
             zipMarketKey.add(zpToBk.ZTS_EU_Query_Ext_ID__c+';'+ zpToBk.ZTS_EU_Market__c);
        }
        
        List<ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c> zipList;
        Map<String,List<ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c>> zipToBrickMap = new Map<String,List<ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c>>();
        
        for(ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c zipToBrick : ziptoBrickList){       
            if(zipToBrickMap.containsKey(zipToBrick.ZTS_EU_Query_Ext_ID__c+';'+zipToBrick.ZTS_EU_Market__c)){
                zipToBrickMap.get(zipToBrick.ZTS_EU_Query_Ext_ID__c+';'+zipToBrick.ZTS_EU_Market__c).add(zipToBrick);                    
            }else{
                zipList = new List<ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c>();
                zipList.add(zipToBrick);
                zipToBrickMap.put(zipToBrick.ZTS_EU_Query_Ext_ID__c+';'+zipToBrick.ZTS_EU_Market__c,zipList);
            }
        }
    
        
        for(Account acc:accList){
           String zipcode = (acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c == ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.MARKET_VAL)?(acc.ZTS_EU_State_County_Value__c != null ? acc.ZTS_EU_State_County_Value__c : ''):
                                                (acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c==ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.UK_MARKET_VAL ? (acc.ZTS_EU_UK_PC4_from_Postalcode__c != '' ? acc.ZTS_EU_UK_PC4_from_Postalcode__c : ''):
                                                (acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c != null ? acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c:''));
                                                
            if(!String.isBlank(zipcode) && zipToBrickMap.containsKey(zipcode+';'+acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c)){
                List<ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c> zipBrickList = zipToBrickMap.get(zipcode+';'+acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c);

                for(ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c z : zipBrickList){
                  acc.ZTS_EU_BrickCode__c = z.ZTS_EU_BrickCode__r.Name;
                 lstBricks.add(acc);

     }
   }
          if(lstBricks.size()>0){
              
                insert lstBricks;
                System.debug('Insert Successful');
          }     
 }
}
```

}
}

Thanks,
Raghu

Comment: the assignment starting with `acc.ZTS_EU_BrickCode__c` is causing the error because in AfterInsert, u cannot update field values on same record that fired the trigger. u need to assign values in beforeInsert. But then its not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Why inserting the list `lstBricks` which is basically the same accounts that were fired in the insert trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In after trigger the instance of trigger.new is in readonly mode so`acc.ZTS_EU_BrickCode__c = z.ZTS_EU_BrickCode__r.Name` is creating the issue. Here you are trying to update the trigge.new instance which is only possible in before trigger not in after trigger.

```
        for(Account acc:accList){
           account accObjTemp = new account();
           accObjTemp = acc;
           String zipcode = (acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c == ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.MARKET_VAL)?(acc.ZTS_EU_State_County_Value__c != null ? acc.ZTS_EU_State_County_Value__c : ''):
                                                (acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c==ZTS_EU_GlobalConstants.UK_MARKET_VAL ? (acc.ZTS_EU_UK_PC4_from_Postalcode__c != '' ? acc.ZTS_EU_UK_PC4_from_Postalcode__c : ''):
                                                (acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c != null ? acc.ZTS_EU_Zip_Postal_Code__c:''));
                                                
            if(!String.isBlank(zipcode) && zipToBrickMap.containsKey(zipcode+';'+acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c)){
                List<ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c> zipBrickList = zipToBrickMap.get(zipcode+';'+acc.ZTS_EU_Market__c);

                for(ZTS_GL_ZipToBrick__c z : zipBrickList){
                  accObjTemp.ZTS_EU_BrickCode__c = z.ZTS_EU_BrickCode__r.Name;
                 lstBricks.add(accObjTemp);

     }
   }
          if(lstBricks.size()>0){
              
                insert lstBricks;
                System.debug('Insert Successful');
          }     
 }
```